# Remover letras e caracteres especiais em um select

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho na minha tabela o campo `documento` com os seguintes dados:

Como faço para selecionar somente os números desses registros retirando as letras e os caracteres especiais?

| DOCUMENTO |
| --- |
| CPF-12345698-35 |
| CPF=05604968-34 |
| CPF-:033369328-32 |
| CPF-056904968-31 |

Resultado esperado: De: `CPF-12345698-35` Para: `1234569835`

Comment: Já vi uma resposta a isso aqui mas não a consigo encontrar.

Comment: @bfavaretto o HTML foi apenas para formatar o conteudo!

Comment: Ok Vitor. Editei pra dar uma limpeza nas suas marcas de formatação, veja como dá pra conseguir o mesmo resultado visual sem nenhum HTML.

Comment: Vc precisa mesmo que esse procedimento seja executado no banco? Pq não faz esse replace na programação? Além de ser mais fácil, vai ter mais performance...

Comment: @rizidoro estou fazendo a conversão de uma database para outra utilizando a query insert into(values,...) Select values ... e gostaria de retirar as letras e os caracteres especiais no próprio select! mas se não conseguir um solução vou ter que realizar na programação.

Comment: A meu ver a melhor forma seria mesmo tratar esses dados numa linguagem de alto nível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única maneira fazendo pelo banco seria criando um [`Function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Obs: talvez não seja tão performático, mas seria uma forma, talvez não a melhor em relação a grande dados mas, se for poucos dados, ou uma tela com paginação, não vai ter tanto problemas de performace.

*Pelo que eu percebi seria uma forma prática para sua conversão*.

**Function:**

*Obs: Aonde está `testdb` coloque o nome do seu banco e rode esse script de criação no referente banco*

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `testdb`.`GetNumber` (field varchar(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ls INTEGER;
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    DECLARE str varchar(100);
    SET ls  = (select length(field));
    SET i   = 1;
    SET str = "";
    WHILE i <= ls DO            
        IF ((substring(field, i,1) REGEXP '[0-9]') <> 0) THEN
            SET str = CONCAT(str, convert(substring(field, i,1) USING UTF8));           
        END IF;
        SET i = i  + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN str;
END;
```

**Usando:**

```
select GetNumber('0cpf:dlbaa25545..5531A');
```

**Saida:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer o seguinte *select*:

```
select replace(replace('12345698-35','-',''),'.','')
```

Comment: obrigado pela atencao, no exemplo acima esta retirando o hífen e o ponto, como faria para tirar as letras 'CPF' ou qualquer outro tipo de letra?

Comment: para isso tera que fazer algo assim:

SELECT
    person,
    replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_number,' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'-','') as phone_number
FROM
    people
WHERE
    phone_number RLIKE '^[+]?[-() 0-9]+$';

usando o where para pegar somente o que precisa

Comment: usar tanto replace tornará sua query lenta, pense nisso sem esquecer o volume de dados, quantidade de transações executadas em determinado intervalo de tempo, quantidade de transações totais no banco referido e o quanto isso pode afetar o sistema.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

```
UPDATE CLIENTES SET CPF = REPLACE (CPF, '-' , '')
```

E depois

```
UPDATE CLIENTES SET CPF = REPLACE (CPF, '.' , '')
```

Pronto, irá ficar apenas os números.

Comment: Não fui eu quem votei negativo, mas acho que não é este o objetivo da pergunta. A ideia era, tal como o título da pergunta afirma, remover os caracteres especiais no `SELECT`, e não simplesmente extirpá-los do banco de dados. Isso daí de retirar no banco [já foi sugerido antes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16031/remover-letras-e-caracteres-especiais-em-um-select#comment29454_16031) e [o autor da pergunta disse que não é o que ele quer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16031/remover-letras-e-caracteres-especiais-em-um-select#comment29463_16031).

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    string NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
    ('003Preliminary Examination Plan'),
    ('Coordination005'),
    ('Balance1000sheet')

SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-
9]%', string + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    string) + 1) AS Number
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo a dica dada pelo @user6026, mas tive problema com a lentidão, me parece que a função é um pouco lenta na execução, mesmo com so devidos campos tratados, fiz vários teste.

Como a ideia é tratar somente CPF e CNPJ, acabei fazendo uma outra função para tratar somente esses casos, veja abaixo:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fLimpaCPFCNPJ`(`str` VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
return replace(replace(replace(str, '/', ''), '-', ''), '.', '');
END
```

Vale lembrar que não sou DBA e gostaria que aqueles que tem mais experiencia pudessem fazer as devidas correções.

Nos testes foi muito mais rapida

Answer (score -1):

use a função case com a REGEXP:

```
case 
    when numero  REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' then numero
    else 0
end as numero
```

Answer (score -2):

Poderia fazer assim também:

```
select replace('12345698-35',REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]+$','')
```

Comment: A função REGEXP do mysql não é usada para esse fim. Ela retorna um booleano apenas dizendo se a REGEXP foi encontrada ou não...

Comment: hummmm sorry tentei