# Tirar letras de campo no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho um campo com informações neste padrão: `"PLC__Line" 34355655413.3912`. 
O que posso utilizar para tirar as letras, _ e " em um select, deixando apenas os números e o ponto?

No PostgreSQL sei que existe a função translate, mas o que pode ser feito no MYSQL?

Edit 1: Com a function abaixo eu consegui tirar as letras, porém o ponto também sumiu, e ele é importante. Como posso editar essa function para que ela deixe também o ponto?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `testdb`.`GetNumber` (field varchar(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
DECLARE ls INTEGER;
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE str varchar(100);
SET ls  = (select length(field));
SET i   = 1;
SET str = "";
WHILE i <= ls DO            
    IF ((substring(field, i,1) REGEXP '[0-9]') <> 0) THEN
        SET str = CONCAT(str, convert(substring(field, i,1) USING UTF8));           
    END IF;
    SET i = i  + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN str;
END;
```

Comment: Esse texto `"PLC__Line" ` é padrão ou ele pode mudar?

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco mais descobri aqui no fórum uma questão igual a sua e com uma resposta que foi aceita, segue o link: [Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16031/remover-letras-e-caracteres-especiais-em-um-select)

Comment: Pedro, pode mudar.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente criar a seguinte função:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphanum; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION alphanum( str CHAR(255) ) RETURNS CHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

Depois utilizá-la da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT alphanum('"PLC__Line" 34355655413.3912');
```

Mais detalhes sobre a solução no **SOen**: [How to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-mysql)

---

Outra forma, também com recurso a uma função:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (val varchar(255)) RETURNS tinyint 
 RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';

 CREATE FUNCTION NumericOnly (val VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
 IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

 IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;

 SET idx = LENGTH(val);
 WHILE idx > 0 DO
 IF IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN
 SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");
 SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;
 END IF;
 SET idx = idx - 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN val;
  END;
```

Utilização:

```
SELECT NumericOnly('"PLC__Line" 34355655413.3912');
```

Mais detalhes sobre a solução no **SOen**: [MYSQL query will remove characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068063/mysql-query-will-remove-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Esse foi o resultado que obtive com a função: PLCLine343556554133912

Comment: Resposta editada. Outra solução incluída.

Answer (score 0):

Com o link enviado pelo R. Santos, pude criar minha function que deu certo:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `meubanco`.`GetNumber` (field varchar(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
DECLARE ls INTEGER;
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE str varchar(100);
SET ls  = (select length(field));
SET i   = 1;
SET str = "";
WHILE i <= ls DO            
    IF ((substring(field, i,1) REGEXP '[0-9.]') <> 0) THEN
        SET str = CONCAT(str, convert(substring(field, i,1) USING UTF8));           
    END IF;
    SET i = i  + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN str;
END;
```